# How to specify the repository url and working path with svn?

Tags: svn

I'm using cron to commit my changes with svn.

I was wondering how I can refer to the correct repository and specify the location of my working copy.

More in detail what should I add to:

```
svn commit -m "Description here"
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, the easiest way would be to do a `cd` to your working copy directory, so everything is set properly. Something like :

```
#!/bin/sh
cd myrepo
svn commit -m "message"
cd -
```

By the way, I think using cron to commit is a **very** bad idea. You should only commit when your code at least compiles, and you can't be sure it does when the cron shows up.

Comment: or `svn commit -m "msg" myrepo` that is even easier

Comment: Well, I've been told that I could use svn to create backups of my website. In this way I can also synch remote and local versions. I was actually looking for a good solution without having to pay for the required disk space.

Comment: If this is only a backup solution, you could try using something like dropbox. SVN (or any VCS) has all kind of versionning-related side you probably won't be using.

Answer (score 0):

your working copy always has a reference to the correct repository - ie the repo the WC was checked out from. When you perform a commit, it will send your changes back to that repo.

You can change the repo (or branch) that the WC refers to using svn switch or svn relocate.